# Variable in a Variable in Django Template

Tags: python, django

I have global variable accessible from every HTML file.
The variable is called `canAccessClients`. Its a list of objects (clients) to which the logged user has access. It is mainly used in menu, so user can see only his clients. I can find the client's logo (its url) by `canAccessClients.<some_index>.picture.url`.

Now, I have one page where are only some clients.

I know the ID of these clients.

This client ID is not obviously the same as index in list of `canAccessClients`.

Because `canAccessClients` is only a list of client objects.

Now I need to show logo for same client which I know his ID.

I do it (maybe to bad idea, but works) by finding iterating through `canAccessClients` and looking for the needed ID.

```
{% for client in canAccessClients %}
   {% if client.id == client_data.CLIENT_ID %}
      <img class="client-menu-logo" src="{{ canAccessClients.{{ forloop.counter }}.picture.url }}" alt="logo">
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works and is ok, but... I need to pass `forloop.counter` variable into `canAccessClients.<some_id>.picture.url`, this does not work.

How can I use variable in some other variable in path like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may [write your own template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) to achieve this. Example:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_image_url_by_id(id):
    url = Client.objects.get(pk=id).image_url # get image url from database
    return url
```

and in template:

```
{% with get_image_url_by_id forloop.counter as image_url %}
{{ image_url }}
```

Comment: Thaks! That worked. I used ```@register.simple_tag
def get_client_logo_url(id):
    return Clients.objects.get(pk=id).picture.url``` and then ```{% get_client_logo_url client_data.CLIENT_ID %}```